# CSS display none mobile and tablet are shown in same query

Tags: html, css

i have the following code / CSS what i am trying to do is only display one type of menu depending on the screensize / device (Mobile, tablet, desktop) however my mobile and my tablet are always shown together.

Can anyone see what i might be missing?

```css
.desktop-nav {
  display: none;
}

.tablet-nav {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width:320px) {
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
  .tablet-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width:801px) {
  .tablet-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1281px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-nav">
  Desktop
  
</div>
<div class="tablet-nav">
  Tablet
</div>
<div class="mobile-nav">
  Mobile
</div>
```

Comment: why don't use min width with max width for perform media query?

Comment: `min-width` is a *minimum*, so any size that is above the minimum width will return TRUE for that boolean test. Therefore you should use the `max-width` criteria and work downwards from the maximum size a display change is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use max-width instead.

Here's what your code is saying, in plain English:

- Hide all the menus
- However, if it's bigger than 320px, show the mobile menu button
- And if it's bigger than  480px, show the tablet menu button
- And the ones after that basically just get in the way of things, so you can remove those.

You should use some different media queries instead, like the ones in the code below, which use max-width.

I have also changed them to be more realistic for those devices.

```css
/* desktops */
.desktop-nav {
  display: block;
}

.tablet-nav {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  /* tablets */
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* mobiles */
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-nav">
  Desktop
  
</div>
<div class="tablet-nav">
  Tablet
</div>
<div class="mobile-nav">
  Mobile
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As i write in comment use `max-width` for perfom query like:

```css
@media (max-width:599px) {
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:1024px) {
 .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}



@media (min-width:1025px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-nav">
  Desktop
  
</div>
<div class="tablet-nav">
  Tablet
</div>
<div class="mobile-nav">
  Mobile
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to overwrite `.mobile-nav` class on @media `600px` and `801px`.

There, you have rewritten `.tablet-nav` but have not rewritten `.mobile-nav` so it is set to the last class of @media `480px` which is set as `display: block`.

```css
.desktop-nav {
  display: none;
}

.tablet-nav {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width:320px) {
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .mobile-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
  .tablet-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:801px) {
  .tablet-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1281px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: block;
  }
  .tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-nav">
  Desktop
  
</div>
<div class="tablet-nav">
  Tablet
</div>
<div class="mobile-nav">
  Mobile
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `min-width` and `max-width` in media queries.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
 .desktop-nav, .mobile-nav {
   display: none;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
 .tablet-nav, .mobile-nav {
   display: none;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .desktop-nav, .tablet-nav {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-nav">
  Desktop
</div>

<div class="tablet-nav">
  Tablet
</div>
<div class="mobile-nav">
  Mobile
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `.mobile-nav { display: none; }` in @media (min-width:600px). check link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-quddzk?file=style.css) to see result.
But that's a lot of media queries. you can optimize that. and keep in mind when you put something in min-width 320. it will be excuted for all widths > 320. so if you don't want it to work like in 768. you should add class there and change it.

Comment: Welcome to snack overgrowth, sadly your answer is not the full solution to the issue presented by the OP.

Comment: snack overgrowth? what's happening? @Martin

Comment: @cornonthecob There's way to many delicious snacks here (such as Corn on the Cob `;-)` ) ... some might say a bit of an excessive growth on "code snacking" whereby people drop in, for simple questions to be answered without hanging around for the "meal" of learning why the issue occured and how to avoid future repetitions `:-)`

Comment: ps. The above is not directed at either @cornonthecob or SofienRhouma